# Cognito / S3 User Specific Policies

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using the AWS SDK for Android alongside Cognito to authenticate users (via Login With Amazon) to my AWS resources. What I am *attempting* to do is to setup an S3 bucket like so:

```
./my-bucket
  ├── first_user@email.com
  └── second_user@email.com
```

So, the `my-bucket` bucket will have folders based on the user's e-mail address.

My first stab to setup the policy was as such:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/${www.amazon.com:user_id}",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/${www.amazon.com:user_id}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As a test, I am trying to download a folder for a user like so:

```java
final Map logins = new HashMap();
logins.put("www.amazon.com", token);
credentialsProvider.withLogins(logins);

final TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
MultipleFileDownload download = transferManager.downloadDirectory("my-bucket", "first_user@email.com", new File("/sdcard/Download"));
```

However, when I run this I get a "Forbidden" exception. If I modify the policy to explicitly reference `first_user@email.com` rather than `${www.amazon.com:user_id}` it works fine.

### Question

1. Is this even possible to be able to use the LWA user's e-mail address to configure it like this?
2. Is there a way to log actually *what* parameters are happening when I make a request?

I've seen references [like this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingWIF.html#CreatingWIF-userid) but I'm not sure which ones actually apply. It would be fantastic if I were somehow able to **see** what values are coming across when I make a request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. No it is not possible to do this with Cognito or web identity federation with just Login with Amazon. The identifiers returned in this flow are pseudo-anonymous. Cognito IDs will be of the form **us-east-1:abcd-123456-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx**. If you use Login with Amazon directly, the IDs would be of the form **amzn-1234567890**.
2. The IDs vended from Cognito are available on the credentials provider by simply calling the *getIdentityId* method. If you are using the raw web identity federation flow, the [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/model/AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult.html) contains the values for the provider, application/audience and user id.

Comment: It's not vital that the folder be the e-mail; I was just confused because I had no idea _what_ variables were available to me. Is there a way to get that?

Comment: Also, from what you said, I think then if I use the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}`, on the device I just need to use the return value from `getIdentityId` and I should be fine.

Comment: @Levi You are correct, `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` and `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}` are the variables you can use.

Comment: @BobKinney what's the difference between `aud` and `sub`?

Comment: @ChrisH `aud` is the *audience* of the token, in the Cognito case, this is the identity pool id. `sub` is the *subject* of the token, which is the Cognito identity id.

Comment: @bobkinney "aud is the audience of the token, in the Cognito case, this is the identity pool id. sub is the subject of the token, which is the Cognito identity id. " your documentation doesn't explicitly state this anywhere that I could see, I searched for hours.

Comment: @DukeDougal It is in the [IAM documentation](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html). While not explicitly stated, it is implied through multiple examples in the [Cognito docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html) as well.

Comment: Is it possible to *create* a new user folder this way, e.g. do a PUT /sub with the policy shown above? (This doesn't seem to work for me).