# IAM Policy for S3 folder access based on Cognito ID

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have created an IAM policy to allow Cognito users to write to my S3 bucket, but I would like to restrict them to folders based on their Cognito ID. I've followed Amazon's instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html) and created a policy that looks like this:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myappfolder/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
    ]
}
```

But when I try to upload using the v2 of the AWS iOS SDK I get an access denied error.

If I modify the last path component of the resource to replace `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` with the explicit `identityId` value I am getting from the SDK's `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` it works.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myappfolder/us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx*"
    ]
}
```

My understanding was that these should equate to the same thing. Am I missing something in my policy, or should I be using a different path in my upload request?

** ***Update*** **

I originally had this problem in iOS, so tonight I tried doing the same thing in node.js and the result is identical. Here is the simple code I am using in node:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(AWSParams);

AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {

    if (!err) {

        console.log("Cognito Identity Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);

        var bucketName = 'ch123_test_bucket';

        var keyName = AWS.config.credentials.identityId + '.txt';

        var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Hello World!'};

        s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
        });
}
```

And I get the same results that I get with iOS: unless I supply an explicit cognito ID in the IAM policy the API responds with 403.

I've stripped my IAM policy down to the very bare minimum. This doesn't work:

```
{
  "Statement": [
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
     "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::ch123_test_bucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
      ]
  }
 ]
}
```

This does:

```
{
"Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::ch123_test_bucket/us-east-1:68a5dc49-6cc7-4289-8257-d3d5636f7034*"
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I don't see what I'm missing here...the only documentation I've been able to find always shows the same example Resource value that I've been using.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first policy you included does not match the second. Are you sure they are the same? Could you include the code you are using in your app? Are you using the transfer manager?

Comment: @BobKinney I've updated my question to show a simple node.js example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @ChrisH, Thanks for your detailed question. I just have a comment and a question. My comment: this line `var s3 = new AWS.S3();` should be after setting credentials (in third line), otherwise, errors will happen. And, the question is: What you wrote is for unauthenticated users, how would you do the same for Authenticated ones? Thanks!

Comment: How did you peek into the ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} IAM variable? I'm using Federated Identities and need to see what is being passed into that variable. I have a feeling when used with S3 and Federated Identities, the colon (:) is being converted to %3A and breaking the match from the Gateway API passed URL encoded string to the IAM variable in the policy resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently an issue with the roles generated via the Cognito console in combination with policy variables. Please update your roles' access policy to include the following to ensure policy variables are evaluated correctly:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17"
```

**2014-09-16 Update:** We have updated the Amazon Cognito console to correct this issue for **new** roles created via the Identity Pool creation wizard. Existing roles will still need to make the modification noted above.

Comment: That was crucial, I spent 3 hours looking for it... Thanks very much! You should **really** correct the [guide for DynamoDB on Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) because it's the one I followed and indeed, it doesn't have this version field!

Comment: @Dadou apologies for the issues. Part of the reason it doesn't have the version is because the policy listed there doesn't require it as it doesn't use policy variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing last slash.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": ["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject"],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/cognito/myappfolder/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
    ]
}
```

Also try to consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679206/cognito-s3-user-specific-policies).

Comment: Thanks but the trailing '/' is not making any difference. The SO question you linked to confirms what I already thought...and suggests that my IAM policy should be working.